# TSQL - Parsing substring out of larger string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a bunch of rows with values that look like below. It's json extract that I unfortunately have to parse out and load. Anyway, my json parsing tool for some reason doesn't want to parse this full column out so i need to do it in TSQL. I only need the unique_id field:

```
[{"unique_id":"12345","system_type":"Test System."}]
```

I tried the below SQL but it's only returning the first 5 characters of the whole column. I know what the issue is which is I need to know how to tell the substring to continue until the 4th set of quotes which comes after the value. I'm not sure how to code the substring like that.

```
select substring([jsonfield],CHARINDEX('[{"unique_id":"',[jsonfield]), 
CHARINDEX('"',[jsonfield]) - CHARINDEX('[{"unique_id":"',[jsonfield]) + 
LEN('"')) from etl.my_test_table
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: " Anyway, my json parsing tool for some reason doesn't want to parse this full column"   Have you tried posting a question about this before looking for a TSQL workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged 2016, why not use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [SampleData] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [SampleData]
                      )
VALUES ( N'[{"unique_id":"12345","system_type":"Test System."}]' )
        ,( N'[{"unique_id":"1234567","system_type":"Test System."},{"unique_id":"1234567_2","system_type":"Test System."}]' )

SELECT b.[unique_id]
FROM   @TestData [a]
CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON([a].[SampleData], '$')
           WITH (
                    [unique_id] NVARCHAR(100) '$.unique_id'
                ) AS [b];
```

Giving you:

```
unique_id
---------------
12345
1234567
1234567_2
```

You can get all the fields as well, just add them to the WITH clause:

```
SELECT [b].[unique_id]
     , [b].[system_type]
FROM   @TestData [a]
CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON([a].[SampleData], '$')
           WITH (
                    [unique_id] NVARCHAR(100) '$.unique_id'
                  , [system_type] NVARCHAR(100) '$.system_type'
                ) AS [b];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take it step by step

First get everything to the left of system_type

```
SELECT LEFT(jsonfield, CHARINDEX('","system_type":"',jsonfield) as s
FROM -- etc
```

Then take everything to the right of `"unique_id":"`

```
SELECT RIGHT(S, LEN(S) - (CHARINDEX('"unique_id":"',S) + 12)) as Result
FROM (
  SELECT LEFT(jsonfield, CHARINDEX('","system_type":"',jsonfield) as s
  FROM -- etc
) X
```

Note, I did not test this so it could be off by one or have a syntax error, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Shnugo -- sure, and if someone does a search based on the subject then my answer might be helpful, so I'll not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If your *larger string* ist just a simple JSON as posted, the solution is very easy:

```
SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(N'[{"unique_id":"12345","system_type":"Test System."}]','$[0].unique_id');
```

[`JSON_VALUE()` needs SQL-Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and will extract one single value from a specified path.